# How do you determine step precedence in BDD

Tags: python, testing, bdd, pytest

Consider these steps:

```
# Step A
@when(parsers.parse('I edit user {user} in {account}'))
@when('I edit user <user> in <account>')
def when_I_edit_user_in_account(user, account):

# Step B
@when(parsers.parse('I edit user {user}'))
@when('I edit user <user>')
def when_I_edit_user(user):
```

I am wondering how BDD determines which step to choose. In my step examples it always chooses step B even if my step is:

```
When I edit user Tom in Main Account
```

Does it always pick the shortest matching step? Is there a way to change this? Are there any known design patterns to this problem?

Things I've tried:

- Changing steps order in the code (Thinking maybe matches first one found)
- Change the steps verbiage (works but not really a solution)

Are the steps wrong by design? Should I always force an account passed?

Notes: pytest-bdd
http://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/